# PHP - create one page that loads data from previous page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page which shows a list of date in a table populated with data from MySQL.

fields I show on page 1 are

```
firstname
lastname
email
```

On page 2 I want to have the full information for the record.

How do I create a page that when a user clicks on `firstname` as an `<a href="">` link it automatically loads the information as opposed to creating seperate pages for every record?

Comment: Pass that particular  record ID (mysql record ID) in query string encoded format and on next page with the help of `$_GET` OR `$_REQUEST` grab that query string value. Then decode that value and use in your query to fetch the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the id which is part of the record gotten from the mysql table, then send a GET request to the second page which in turn fetches the whole record in the table...

## PAGE 1:

```
/**
 * ..Establish the connection to MySQL, Selects Database..
 * ..Fetch few columns of all records..
 */
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,firstname,lastname FROM records_table");
 //Draw a table to hold the records
 echo "<table>";
 echo "<tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Email</th><tr>";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     echo "<tr>";
     //Using the id of a record to create ahref link thats sends a get data to the second page
     echo "<td><a href='second.php?id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['firstname']."</a></td>";
     echo "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
```

## PAGE 2 (second.php):

```
$record_id = (int) $_GET['id'];
//Fetch the full details of this record...

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM records_table WHERE id = ".$record_id."");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

//List out the details..
echo "FIRSTNAME: ".$row['firstname'];
echo "LASTNAME: ".$row['lastname'];
echo "EMAIL: ".$row['email'];
//... as many column you may have...
```

Comment: How do i then use this second page to then be able to update or delete a record form second page using the id and by having form buttons on it that send it to a update.php for update button 'submit' or delete.php for delete button 'submit' it does seem to select that record

Answer (score 0):

You could try to append `<site 1>?variable=value` to your href and call that from your second site via PHP and `?_GET['variable']`

For example:

HTML

```
<a href="site2.php?firstname=foo">Click me!</a>
```

PHP

```
<?php echo $_GET['firstname']; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks willove give them a try see which works best for how I would like it to. 